# Dynamic array json parsing

Tags: arrays, json, go

I am trying to parse json to go lang struck but some how the object is return empty:

Json Object:

```
`{
    "names": [
        {
            "David": {
                "id": "100",
                "country": "usa",
                "group": [
                    "A1",
                    "A2"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "John": {
                "id": "1",
                "country": "uk",
                "group": [
                    "A1",
                    "A2"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}`
```

GoLang struct:

```
type Data struct {
    Names []Names `json:"names"`
}

type Names struct {
    ID      string   `json:"id"`
    Country string   `json:"country"`
    Group   []string `json:"group"`
}
```

The issue that array contains 2 element David,John somehow it return empty object as the parser has problem to extract the strings David,John

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code sample, which deserializes this JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct `Data's` `Names` field is wrong. It is a slice of `map[string]Names` rather `[]Names`.
So just change it to:

```
Names []map[string]Names `json:"names"`
```

Check the full runnable code at https://play.golang.org/p/IDU0jANRbBn.

Comment: Great its woking , array of string,Map